# RSpec - use test double as block argument

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some Ruby code which looks like this:

```
Something.create do |x|
    x.foo = bar
end
```

I'd like to write a test which uses a double in place of the block argument x, so that I can then call:

```
x_double.should_receive(:foo).with("whatever").
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 specify 'something' do
   x = double
   x.should_receive(:foo=).with("whatever")
   Something.should_receive(:create).and_yield(x)
   # call the relevant method
 end
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but I'd like to nitpick. `Something.should_receive(:create)` is a test - an assertion - but it's not asserting the behaviour stubotnik said he wanted to test.  So I'd differentiate test setup from the behaviour under test by using `Something.stub(:create).and_return(x)` which isn't asserting anything about the behaviour of `Something.create`